# vs2013 shows file checked in, but in git status the file is untracked

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

In Solution Explorer in VS2013 I see a file with a blue lock on it, and when I hover on it it says "checked in". Also, in the Team Explorer the file doesn't show not in "Included changes", not in "Excluded changes", and not in "Untracked files".

However, in `git status` the file does show in "untracked file" (and the file actually is not getting committed to the remote origin).

It it the state of part of the files in my solution (about 20 "missing" files from about 100 total), all are "regular" valid .cs files.

**EDIT: added git output and screenshot**

take for example AccountController.cs

in the VS I see

[image]

and don't see it in Team Explorer at all,

but in `git status` I see it untracked:

```
C:\Dropbox\MyProject\src\MyProject.V5 [master +93 ~0 -0 !]> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .dropbox
        MyProject.Management/App_Data/
        MyProject.Management/Content/dataTables.bootstrap.js
        MyProject.Management/Content/dataTables.responsive.js
        MyProject.Management/Content/jquery.dataTables.js
        MyProject.Management/Controllers/AccountController.cs
        MyProject.Management/Controllers/UsersController.cs
        MyProject.Management/Models/AccountControllerModels.cs
        MyProject.Management/Models/UsersControllerModels.cs
        MyProject.Management/Views/Gifts/
        MyProject.Management/Views/Payments/Ping.cshtml
        MyProject.SmsService/ApplicationPreload.cs
        MyProject.SmsService/Content/
```

Comment: Eventually I added the files via SourceTree, and made the regular checkin/checkout stuff with command line, but nevertheless the issue is annoying - how can I count on VS that it pulls/merges correctly... or should I switch to a different tool for source control matters...

Comment: Screenshots of both VS and the command-line output would be very helpful here.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` that may be getting calculated incorrectly by vs?

Comment: if VS decides that these files are matching .gitignore rules, doesn't it has to list them in "untracked files"?

Comment: from then I decided to use a combination of command line and atlassian sourcetree to work with git instead of VS.